JSPDF HTML to PDF I am having issue on bold placement missing alingment
**For dynamic data I am using creating HTML **

          <div class="prv-blk" id="content-to-print"> 
            <p style="page-break-inside: avoid;"><b>${el.pName || ''}:</b> ${el.pDescription ? el.pDescription + ',' : ''} ${el.ServicePhoneNumber ? el.ServicePhoneNumber + ',' : ''}, 
            ${el.addressLine1 ? el.addressLine1 + ',' : ''}, ${el.addressCity ? el.addressCity + ',' : ''}, 
            ${el.addressPostalCode ? el.addressPostalCode + ',' : ''}, Utah</p>
          </div>

then converting into pdf
await pdf.html(tempContainer, {
      callback: async(pdf) => {
        // Add any footers or headers here if needed
        await this.openPdf(pdf);
      },
      margin: [10, 10, 10, 10], // top, left, bottom, right margins
      autoPaging: 'text', // Automatically add new pages if content overflows
      x: 0,
      y: 50,
      // width: 100,
      html2canvas: {
        scale: 0.5 // Adjusts the resolution of the output
      }
    });

but for bold text its misplacing alingment
enter image description here
I am expecting to bold text to remain its alingment place not break

Might the bold font be a substitution with a similar different font than that of the regular text? That would explain a different geometry.

Thanks Everyone I Found out using  tag separately rather inline work well
${el.pName || ''}:
${el.pDescription ? el.pDescription + ',' 